# margin is set to 15px i change it but nothing changes it is fixed on 15px

Tags: html, css

The margin of the div is already set to 15px. Even when I change it, nothing changes, When I go to inspect element the margins are now set to 0px but the div containers are fixed in their place.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.portfolio {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.portfolioimg {
  height: 60%;
  ;
  width: 90%;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 5px;
}

.description {
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4267B2;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <img class="portfolioimg" src="https://static5.depositphotos.com/1000270/486/i/600/depositphotos_4869272-stock-photo-bengal-cat-light-brown-cream.jpg">
  <p class="title">Oliver</p>
  <p class="description">2 mutual friends</p>
  <button>Add friend</button>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
  <img class="portfolioimg" src="https://static5.depositphotos.com/1000270/486/i/600/depositphotos_4869272-stock-photo-bengal-cat-light-brown-cream.jpg">
  <p class="title">Oliver</p>
  <p class="description">2 mutual friends</p>
  <button>Add friend</button>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
  <img class="portfolioimg" src="https://static5.depositphotos.com/1000270/486/i/600/depositphotos_4869272-stock-photo-bengal-cat-light-brown-cream.jpg">
  <p class="title">Oliver</p>
  <p class="description">2 mutual friends</p>
  <button>Add friend</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline/inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements)

Comment: I've checked, but it is unclear what 'div' you're talking about. The div with `.portfolio` has a margin of 10px, which is exactly what you set it to. So what's going wrong?

Comment: You rarely should apply styles to an entire element type, such as 'div'. It's just not wise.

Comment: Refrain from using static height/width elements, play with min-height/width and max-height/width for a better responsive experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because you style the same `div` twice. `div` and `portfolio` are the same actually. so the `margin` in the `portfolio` **overwrites** the `margin` in `div`. and that's why nothing happens when you change it in `div`.

so it's better to always use the class when you style because your div style like this will apply to any div you add to the page.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  border:solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 7px lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin:50px;
}
  
.portfolio{
  height:250px;
width: 150px;
/* margin:50px; */
}
.portfolioimg{
  height: 60%;;
width:90%;
}
.title{
  font-weight:bold;
font-family:arial;
margin:5px;
}
.description{
  margin:5px;
  font-family:arial;
font-size:14px;
}
button{
  margin:5px;
padding:5px;
color:white;
  background-color:#4267B2;
border:none;
border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="portfolio">
    <img class="portfolioimg" src="https://static5.depositphotos.com/1000270/486/i/600/depositphotos_4869272-stock-photo-bengal-cat-light-brown-cream.jpg">
    <p class="title">Oliver</p>
    <p class="description">2 mutual friends</p>
    <button>Add friend</button>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <img class="portfolioimg" src="https://static5.depositphotos.com/1000270/486/i/600/depositphotos_4869272-stock-photo-bengal-cat-light-brown-cream.jpg">
    <p class="title">Oliver</p>
    <p class="description">2 mutual friends</p>
    <button>Add friend</button>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <img class="portfolioimg" src="https://static5.depositphotos.com/1000270/486/i/600/depositphotos_4869272-stock-photo-bengal-cat-light-brown-cream.jpg">
    <p class="title">Oliver</p>
    <p class="description">2 mutual friends</p>
    <button>Add friend</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks guys really appreciated  i tried to move display:inline-block from div to portfolio and fixed it and i'll definitely consider the advices  you gave

Comment: Don't forget to check as accepted answer and up vote it